# Limited number of tabpages in boostrap 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tabs, bootstrap-5

Using Rails 7 and Bootstrap 5.1

According to this code snippet I managed to get four tabpages. When trying to add a fifth tabpage it is showing only the tab but when clicking on it, the tab seems to be inactiv and it isn't showning any content.
Is the number of tabpages limited to four or do I have to do any configuration?

```
<div>
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home Content</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile Content</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">Messages Content</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">Settings Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do not add "SOLVED" to your question. You can put your acceptance mark on one of the answer, but a question is never truly solved on Stack Overflow. There can always be better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing should prevent you from using more than 4 tabs. There should be something wrong in your HTML. Maybe you can also check your console to see if there's anything wrong occurring with the JS.

Also that would be simpler to help if you provide an example of the non-working situation.

Here is a working example using bootstrap 5, with six tabs used.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home-tab-pane" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <button class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#profile-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="profile-tab-pane" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <button class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#contact-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="contact-tab-pane" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <button class="nav-link" id="other-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#other-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="other-tab-pane" aria-selected="false">Other</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <button class="nav-link" id="yetanother-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#yetanother-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="yetanother-tab-pane" aria-selected="false">Yet another</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <button class="nav-link" id="stillanother-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#stillanother-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="stillanother-tab-pane" aria-selected="false">Still another</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab" tabindex="0">A</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab" tabindex="0">B</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab" tabindex="0">C</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="other-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="other-tab" tabindex="0">D</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="yetanother-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="yetanother-tab" tabindex="0">E</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="stillanother-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="stillanother-tab" tabindex="0">F</div>
  </div>



  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```